# Why is the complex conjugate function (on the upper half plane) not a Möbius transformation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, mobius-transformation

I want to show that the map $z\mapsto -\overline z$ is not a Möbius transformation. I've seen the answer to do something with analytic maps, which we haven't learned, so is there a more basic proof to this?

Comment: What is your definition of Mobius transformation? Presumably, the answer lies there.

Comment: we used the definition $T(z)=\frac {az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb R$ and
$det\begin {bmatrix} a  & b \\ c & d\end {bmatrix} \neq 0$

Comment: in this question, $z \in \mathbb H ^2$

Comment: Set $-\bar z = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ and use particular values to solve for the coefficients. As a hint, what does it have to be in the special case when $z$ is real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it seems a little misguided to prove that $z\to -\overline{z}$ is not a Mobius transformation *without* using the idea of analytic/holomorphic functions (the proof would be quick: $z\to -\overline{z}$ is not holomorphic, while all Mobius maps are holomorphic... done) we can do so.

Suppose $-\overline{z}={az+b\over cz+d}$ for some $a,b,c,d$, for all $z$, and plug in various $z$'s to see the impossibility... For example, from $z=0$, we have $b=0$. From $z=1$, we have $c+d=-(a+b)$. From $z=i$, ...

Comment: The mobius transformation restricted to a subset is equal to the original mobius transformation if it exists. So when $z$ is real you have $\bar z = z$ and when $z$ is imaginary you have $\bar z = -z$, but since $z \ne -z$ these define two different mobius transformations, and so there is no solution.

Comment: @Arthur, oop, thanks, I'll edit.

Comment: @Merosity, indeed, with some pedestrian/limited form of the Identity Principle for Mobius transformations, your comment would succeed directly. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whereas you can easily see that a nontrivial Möbius transformation has at most two fixed points, your transformation is fixed on all points of the imaginary axis.